# Angular2 email validation

Tags: angular, email-validation

I am new in learning Angular2, and I want to make a validation form that verifies emails after a RegEx pattern.

My code looks something like this but I don't have any idea if I am doing it right, or what I did wrong, can somebody please help me a bit?

Thank you!

I fixed it. Thank you a lot everybody.

```html
<div class="alert-email">
    <label for="contactemail">EMAIL: </label>
    <input type="email" id="contactemail" name="contactemail"
           required ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/"
           [(ngModel)]="model.contactemail" #contactemail="ngModel"
           placeholder="Your email" /><br><br>
    <div *ngIf="contactemail.errors && (contactemail.dirty || contactemail.touched)" class="alert-email alert-danger-email"><br>
      <div [hidden]="!contactname.errors.required">
        Email is required
      </div>
      <div [hidden]="!contactname.errors">
        Please input a valid email.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you have to remove the regex delimiter `/`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Try Something like that**

```
<div class="alert-email">
        <label>Email</label>
            <input
                id="contactemail"
                type="text"                
                #contactemail="ngModel"
                [(ngModel)]="model.contactemail"
                required
                pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$">

        <div class="md-errors-spacer" [hidden]="contactemail.valid || contactemail.untouched">
            <div  *ngIf="contactemail.errors && contactemail.errors.required">
                Email is required
            </div>
            <div  *ngIf="contactemail.errors && contactemail.errors.pattern">
                Email is invalid
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: there are new TLDs you should change accordingly

Comment: <label for="CompanyEmail" class="control-label">Company Email</label>
<input id="CompanyEmail" type="text" [(ngModel)]="_user.Email" class="form-control"  pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" required #CompanyEmail="ngModel" placeholder="Please enter Company Email address" />
<div *ngIf="CompanyEmail.invalid && (CompanyEmail.dirty || CompanyEmail.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
<div *ngIf="CompanyEmail.errors.required">
Company Email is required.
        <div *ngIf="CompanyEmail.errors && CompanyEmail.errors.pattern">
            Email is invalid

Comment: Worked for me using Angular5. Copied pattern as-is, copied "Email is invalid" div as-is.

Comment: This looks like yet another ad hoc regex which will accept invalid addresses and reject valid ones. Don't roll your own.

Answer (score 61):

Angular 4 has a built-in "email" validation tag that can be added within the input. E.g.:

```
<input type="email" id="contactemail" email>
```

This will be valid for a series of numbers and letters then an @ then another series of letters. It will not account for the dot after the @ -- for that you can use the "pattern" tag within the input and your standard regex.

Comment: Only available since Angular4

Comment: When using it this way the input is implicitly required - even if not specifying "required". Bug or feature?

Comment: I just noticed the same thing. My form is invalid straight away, even when the email field is left empty.

Comment: How could you use this along with ngClass??
`[ngClass]="{invalid : !email.valid}"`?

Comment: @JakeKieranan `<input type="text" class="form-control" #firstName="ngModel" name="fname" [(ngModel)]="fname" [ngClass]="{invalid : firstName.touched && !fname}">` 

I essentially want to do the same as this, however add the `invalid` class if the email is not valid? So something like this.

`<input type="email" class="form-control" #userEmail="ngModel" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" email [ngClass]="{invalid : email.touched && !fname && !email.pattern}">` 

Where the pattern is checked & the class `invalid` is added if the email is not valid

Comment: Resolved. With this `<input type="text" class="form-control" #userEmail="ngModel" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" [ngClass]="{invalid : userEmail.touched && !userEmail?.valid}" required email>`

Comment: There is no requirement for an e-mail address to end with a .com or anything of the sort.  user@localhost is valid

Comment: what should be the `*ngIf` condition for showing error message??

Comment: @AnkurShah *ngIf="email.errors.email", where email is the reference to the field (starts with #)

Answer (score 30):

Angular 4 Email Validation :

- Use **email** to your input
- If you want **.com** for email use pattern **pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}**

Final :

```
`<input type="email" [(ngModel)]="enterEmail" name="myEmail" #myEmail="ngModel" email pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" required>`
```

Comment: There is an error in `[a-zA-Z0-9.**-**_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}`. The minus char must be escaped. I prefer `^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]*@[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z.-]*[a-zA-Z]{1}[.][a-zA-Z]{2,}$`

Comment: Hint: any regex which contains `{1}` was written by someone who is only just beginning to learn about regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this pattern for your email inputs:

```
^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$
```

[ref](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-pattern-validation-example)

This pattern accepts "sample@domain" also in addition of "sample@domain.dom".
Using this email pattern "sample@domain." is not acceptable and 1 letter domain tld is not allowed ("sample@domain.s" goes wrong).

Answer (score 4):

For multiple email validation in a single field, you can do using the custom email validator.

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class EmailValidator {

public static isValid(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

static isMultiValid(control: FormControl): any {

  console.log(control.value);
  let tempEmail = control.value;
  let invalid = false;
  let regex =/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/g;

  if(tempEmail.indexOf(',') > -1){
    var emails = control.value.split(',');
      for (let email of emails) {
        console.log(email);
        let isValid = EmailValidator.isValid(email)
        if(!isValid){
          return{"email not valid":isValid}
        }
      }
      return null;
  }
  else{
    let email = control.value.split(',');
    if( email == "" || ! regex.test(email)){
        invalid = true;
        return {
            "email not valid": invalid
        };
    }
    console.log("valid");
    return null;

   }
  }
}
```

.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

Comment: Hello & Welcome to StackOverflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the tour, and [How do I write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern worked for me which will accept alphanumeric characters and '.' special character.

```
^[\\w]+(?:\\.[\\w])*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

Answer (score 0):

this pattern email working :

```
 <input  pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$">
```

Answer (score -2):

This `pattern` worked for me :

```
 pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{3,}"
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This One it will work:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+([.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@([a-zA-Z]+([.-]?[a-zA-Z]))[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```