# How to validate an email in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-validators

I am using **FormGroup**, **FormBuilder** and **Validators** class to validate a form in Angular2 app.

This is how I am defining the required validation rules for email and password validation:-

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginFormGroup:FormGroup;
    adminLoginmodel = new Admin('', '', '', 'Emailsss','Passwordsss');  

    constructor(
       private route: ActivatedRoute,
       private router: Router,
       private _adminLogin: AdminLoginService,
       fb: FormBuilder
    ){
         this.loginFormGroup = fb.group({
            'email' : [null, Validators.required],
            'password': [null, Validators.required]
         });
    }
}
```

How can I validate if a given string is a valid email?

**Note:**

Someone has just tried to mark this question as a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366649/angular2-email-validation).

My question specifically asks about implementation of *FormGroup* and *FormBuilder*, which was even stated at the beginning of the question. This is a fine example to show how some good and valid questions get judged unfairly. Hope the moderators and other so-called "stackoverflow-community-builders" won't edit this question to remove this section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366649/angular2-email-validation)

Comment: [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/5695162)

Comment: [`EmailValidator`](https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.loginFormGroup = fb.group({
  'email' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
  'password': [null, Validators.required]
});
```

> Compose multiple validators into a single function that returns the union of the individual error maps.

Comment: Great! This one is the actual answer I needed more. It shows how I can use multiple validation rules! I was about to post a question on how to have multiple validation rules on a single <input>. Validators.compose does the trick. Many many thanks. Moreover, Validators.email also checks whether an email is valid or not. Hence, we don't need the preg match pattern.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: :). I am posting another question. Hope you can help me in that too. :)

Comment: Here's another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49689689/how-to-show-different-validation-messages-for-email-validation-in-angular2-using

Answer (score 1):

You have to use pattern validator with a regex:

```
this.loginFormGroup = fb.group({
    'email' : [null, Validators.pattern('^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$')],
    'password': [null, Validators.required]
});
```

Comment: Email like `tuhindey@gmail.com` isn't  detected as valid mail using your script.

Comment: Build your own regex, that is an example for validating a pattern