# How to show different validation messages for email validation in Angular2 using Validators class?

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder, angular2-form-validation

I am using **FormGroup**, **FormBuilder** and **Validators** class to validate a form in Angular2 app.

This is how I am defining the required validation rules for email and password validation:-

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginFormGroup:FormGroup;
    adminLoginmodel = new Admin('', '', '', 'Emailsss','Passwordsss');  

    constructor(
       private route: ActivatedRoute,
       private router: Router,
       private _adminLogin: AdminLoginService,
       fb: FormBuilder
    ){
         this.loginFormGroup = fb.group({
            'email' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
            'password': [null, Validators.required]
         });
    }
}
```

The code `Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])` checks both whether an email field is empty and whether the provided string is valid email.

However, I don't know how to show different validation message in different cases. Say

1. If email field is empty, I need to display "Please provide an email
   address"
2. If provided email is not valid, then I need to display "Provided email is not a valid email".

Here is how I was displaying validation message in my html:-

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!loginFormGroup.controls['email'].valid && loginFormGroup.controls['email'].touched}">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user red"></i></span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" [formControl]="loginFormGroup.controls['email']" [(ngModel)]="adminLoginmodel.email"/>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!loginFormGroup.controls['email'].valid">You must add an email.</div>
```

How can I show different messages in different cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <input [formControl]="ctrl" />

  <div *ngIf="ctrl.errors?.email">
    Provided email is not a valid email
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="ctrl.errors?.required">
    Please provide an email address
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  ctrl = new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required]));
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvsx6j)

Discussion in the comments proved that the answer to this specific problem is:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="loginFormGroup.controls['email'].hasError('email')">Provide a valid email.</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="loginFormGroup.controls['email'].hasError('required')">Please provide an email address</div>
```

Comment: `<div *ngIf="ctrl.errors?.email"> Provided email is not a valid email </div><div *ngIf="ctrl.errors?.required"> Please provide an email address </div>` doesn't show any messages.

Comment: The live demo is working correctly. In your case you need to change the `*ngIf` expression to `loginFormGroup.get('email').errors?.email` and  `loginFormGroup.get('email').errors?.required`

Comment: `<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="loginFormGroup.get('email').errors?.required">You must add an email.</div>` doesn't display any error message

Comment: `<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="loginFormGroup.controls['email'].hasError('email')">Provide a valid email.</div>` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to display the error message

```
<div *ngIf="loginFormGroup.get('email').touched && loginFormGroup.get('email').hasError('required')">Please provide an email address</div>
  <div *ngIf="loginFormGroup.get('email').touched && loginFormGroup.get('email').hasError('email')">Provided email is not a valid email</div>
```